# Powershell foreach loop with if statements only evaluates first statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, random, foreach

So I have a snippet of my code below. Basically it loops from 1 to a user input. Each loop it generates a random number from 1 to 4 (inclusive), then based on that number it prints a specific word document to the default printer.

If I just run the code without all the if / elseif statements, only printing the value of $ran, then it works perfectly.

However once I put the if / elseif statements in, it only prints file number 1.docx.

Any ideas why the value of $ran seems to remain 1 when im using the if / elseif statements?

Code -

```
1..$count | foreach { $ran = random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5
    if ($ran = 1) {
    Start-Process -FilePath "file1" -Verb Print
    Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
Elseif ($ran = 2){

    Start-Process -FilePath "file2" -Verb Print
    Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
elseif ($ran = 3){

    Start-Process -FilePath "file3" -Verb Print
    Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
elseif ($ran = 4){

    Start-Process -FilePath "file4" -Verb Print
    Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
else {

    Write-Output "Something went wrong!"
    pause
    }
    }
```

Comment: the `=` is for ASSIGNMENT, not for _comparison_. [*grin*] use `-eq` instead.

Comment: also, take a look at the `switch` statement. it is quite good at doing an `if/elseif/else` cascade in a rather neater package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch statement is much prettier and easier to use than a ton of IF statements like you used.  Here's the syntax for a `switch`/

```
$x = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 7
    switch ($x)
    {
        1 {"x was 1"}
        {$_ -in 2,3} {"x was 2 or 3"}
        4 {"x was 4"}
        Default {"x was something else"}
    }
```

You specify a comparison very simply, just matching the value of the variable.  You can also use a scriptblock too for more complex logic.  Finally, `Default` handles anything else not expressly resolved by the other statements.

And here's how to begin rewriting your code with a switch statement.

```
1..$count | foreach { 
    $ran = random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5
    switch ($ran){
        1{
        Start-Process -FilePath "file1" -Verb Print
        Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
        2{
        Start-Process -FilePath "file2" -Verb Print
        Wait-Process "WINWORD"
    }
    #finish the rest here  
}
```